# SHA1 calculation returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, ajax, sha1, cryptojs

I am trying to calculate SHA1 value of a file using javascript.
The file is located on the same directory as index.html and it is loaded using ajax by the name given as a query param.

for example, calling http://localhost:7070/index.html?file=file.zip should calculate SHA1 for file.zip

The following code calculates SHA1 **but the result is different** than what i get using this online tool with SHA1 and uploading the file http://onlinemd5.com/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var file = utils.getUrlVars() && utils.getUrlVars().file;

   if (!file) throw "error - no URL was found. set 'file' in query string.";

   $.ajax({

       url: file,
       success: function(data){
           var sha1= CryptoJS.SHA1(data).toString();
           console.log('sha1 - success', sha1);
       },
       error: function(error){
           console.log('ERROR');
       }

   })
});
```

What is the difference? i guess that the online tool calculates it right (and it also gives me the exact result i get when calculating using Java code), so something in this JS code does it slightly different.

The problem is definitely not in the CryptoJS package since when calculating the string 'hello' using the script generates the following output:

```
sha1 - success aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d
```

And using the online tool you get the same (in uppercase):

```
AAF4C61DDCC5E8A2DABEDE0F3B482CD9AEA9434D
```

The problem is definitely in the format of the data after loading it or the way of using it.

When i use Java to calculate SHA1 i get the same result by calculating it on the files byte array, so it points to the fact that the bytearray i get using this script is somehow different / partial.

Comment: What SHA1SUM are you getting for your file? Is it da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709 ? That would be an empty file. Try comparing the javascript output for a known good simple string. "hello" should yield aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d. If that works well, the error is in the file handling. Maybe the JavaScript isn't allowed to load files from the disk.

Comment: No, the result changes when i change files, it does calculate SHA1 over something related to the file.

Comment: When sending the file contents, did you use header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` or not?

Comment: @neuhaus - hello results the correct value since the CryptoJS.SHA1 function does what it should do, the problem is indeed in handling the file.

Comment: @Mjh - I tries to add contentType in the ajax script but the result didn't change, same SHA1 are produced for the same files

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not incorporate answers into the question - it makes existing answers useless/confusing and makes the question a moving target for other readers.

Comment: `var sha1= CryptoJS.SHA1(data).toString();` I would start by logging and showing what `data` and `sha1` are for known (short) values of data.

Comment: @AD7six - when i log data to console i get a long string of characters which shows me that it does represent a byte stream.

Comment: I am talking about file here, do you want me to put a reference to a real file to download?

Comment: @Eyal - using `contentType` in the `$.ajax` sets the header for the **request**. The header I'm asking about is a **response** header. Your hashing functions must operate using the same binary content, or you will get a different hash result. The `CryptoJS` definitely implements hashing correctly, so that means the mistake is somewhere at the sending / receiving part, not in the library itself.

Comment: I can't find the place to declare this response header, i guess that it might be the issue, however i got no clue about where the change should be done.

Comment: @Eyal I'm asking you to debug by pointing at a small file (e.g. a simple favicon) and **update the question** showing what `data` and `sha1` are - What you'll probably find is that `data` does _not_ match the contents of the file - which would indicate that the problem isn't the crypto lib but  instead how you are obtaining the file's contents.

Comment: @AD7six - allright, i have updated that when calculating a string's value using the script provides the right hash, so it must be in the way i handle the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to solve this eventually, the solution is pure JS with no Ajax involved:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var url = utils.getUrlVars() && utils.getUrlVars().url;

if (!url) throw "error - no URL was found. set 'url' in query string.";

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";

oReq.onreadystatechange = function(e) {

    if (oReq.readyState == 4 && oReq.status == 200) {
        console.log('xhr success');
        success(e);
    } else if (oReq.readyState == 4 && oReq.status != 200){
        console.log('xhr error');
        error(e);
    }
}

var success = function() {
    var blob = oReq.response; 
    var sha1 = CryptoJS.algo.SHA1.create(); 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var arrbuffer = e.target.result.slice(0, e.target.result.byteLength);
        var bytes = CryptoJS.enc.u8array.parse(new Uint8Array(arrbuffer));
        sha1.update(bytes);
        var sha1res = sha1.finalize().toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
        // print results
        console.log('sha1 - success', sha1res);
    }
};

var error = function(){
    IJavaScriptImplementer.onError(JSON.stringify(error));
    IJavaScriptImplementer.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}

oReq.send(null);
});
```

As you cam see, the file is requested as a blob and is being read as one slice (you can also do it slice by slice but in my case the files are small), then the bytes are read and calculated into the SHA1 value.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual for .ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you need to set the `dataType` option to `text`, otherwise it will try to guess the type and then `text` is never an option.

Comment: tried to add the following but result is the same: dataType: 'text'